# Why is this async method blocking the UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, async-await

I am struggling with an issue which is raised by this piece of code:

```
    private int FPS = 60;

    void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        WebviewContentWorker();
    }

    private async void WebviewContentWorker()
    {
        WebViewBrush wvb = new WebViewBrush();
        wvb.SetSource(WebView);
        wvb.Redraw(); //we must redraw at least once before collapsing the WebView
        WebView.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

        while (true)
        {
            webViewContent.Background = wvb; //webViewContent is a canvas
            await Task.Delay(1000 / FPS);
            wvb.Redraw();
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to find a workaround for XAML's `WebView` which I find very sloppy. I want to be able to draw things on top of it but I can't so what I'm basically doing is taking snapshots of the `WebView` (using the `WebViewBrush`) repeatedly (based on the `int FPS` field) and then setting the `Background` property of the canvas named "`webViewContent`" with this snapshot. The aim is to have animations displayed on the canvas while still being able to draw on top of it (if I don't do these fast snapshots, the canvas will display a still image).

It is working fine now (I successfully redirect any `Tapped` event to the inside of the `WebView` so that clicks on buttons/links/... are properly handled) but it is somehow laggy. The slow bit being `wvb.Redraw()` I was wondering how I could improve the performance of my thread. It looks like the UI is responsive *during* the `Task.Delay` but is blocked otherwise...

Any input/advice is very welcome!

Edit:
Here is how I timed the `Redraw` call (which I believe is what causes the problem since removing it makes the application very responsive):

```
        while (true)
        {
            webViewContent.Background = wvb;
            await Task.Delay(1000 / FPS);
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            wvb.Redraw();
            sw.Stop();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
```

Which gives me these results in the output window:

```
0,094
0,058
0,041
0,053
0,057
0,038
0,032
0,033
0,032
0,038
0,035
0,03
0,042
0,028
0,044
0,031
0,033
0,029
0,034
0,03
0,052
0,029
```

So not so much after all...

Comment: About how long does your `Redraw` method take to run?  Also, is it really imperative to have 60 FPS?  Can you lower it a bit without the display being too jerky?

Comment: I tried using `StopWatch` ealier today and the `(double) Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` property returned values between 0,1XXX and 0,3XXX I believe.

Comment: If it's taking a third of a millisecond then I can't see how it would be blocking the UI for long enough to be perceptible by a person, even if done 60 times a second.  That's still plenty of time for the UI's message loop to stay responsive.  Perhaps you weren't properly timing it under the same conditions that you're actually using it under.

Comment: I edited my first post with the correct results and how I did timed the operation, have a look!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It looks like the UI is responsive during the Task.Delay but is blocked otherwise...

Well yes. That's *exactly* what's happening. `Task.Delay` is the only chance you're giving the UI thread to work. Your asynchronous method is executing on the UI thread - as soon as the "delaying" task completes, you'll end up with a continuation waiting to execute on the UI thread which will redraw and then delay again.

Fundamentally, if your `Redraw` method is too slow to be called ~60 times per second, you need a different approach.

It's very important to understand that `async` *doesn't* put the method onto a different thread - it just allows you to act asynchronously. (Your description and title suggest that you expected your method not to be using the UI thread for any significant time.)

Additionally, as Stephen Cleary says, using a `DispatcherTimer` is a generally-better way of executing code periodically on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I indeed thought that `async` automatically built an FSM on a different thread. You wrote about finding a different approach, do you have any clues or ideas about that?

Comment: @RedPolygon: Well basically you need to either make `Redraw` faster or execute it less often - it's as simple as that. Or maybe punt some of the redraw work to a different thread if you can, but it's hard to know without more information.

Comment: Doing some of `Redraw` work in another thread would be great but I did not write the method so I'll see if I feel brave enough to dive into the MSIL (I just started learning WinRT). Let's hope that a better `WebView` will be released along with the 8.1, maybe we'll know more at the BUILD event next week. Thanks anyway for the advices.

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Delay` is not particularly efficient for repeatedly doing many short timeouts. You'll generate a lot of garbage.

I would recommend using a dispatcher timer or similar for this scenario.

Comment: While I agree that `Task.Delay` isn't an ideal fit here, I wouldn't have expected the amount of garbage generated by `Task.Delay` to really be significant. It's only going to be called 60 times per second at most, after all... and the GC can handle *really* quite a lot of garbage...

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it works a bit better but it's still too much laggy. I've got a custom control on top of the canvas which you can move around and you can definetely feel the delay.